# tapGesture hyperLink swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an image and I want it to go to my website when anyone hit the picture
I used tapGesture to convert the image to a big button , but what I don't know how to do it , is that I want the app to take the user to my website when the user hit the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends a bit on where you want the link to open. The two standard approaches are to either [open the URL in a UIWebView](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/webview-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift) you provide inside the app, or to tell the system to open the link in the mobile Safari browser (which will send your app to the background).

To me it sounds like it this second behaviour you want. You can achieve it by telling the UIApplication to open the URL, like so:

```
@IBAction func linkTapped(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   if let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/") {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
   }
}
```

## Edit:

Some more info on how to set this up in the way you described: in your `viewDidLoad`, set up your gesture recognizer like this:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "linkTapped:")
self.yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
self.yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Make sure the IBOutlet for `yourImageView` is connected correctly. Then simply add the code given in the original answer as a method to the same class containing your `viewDidLoad` method. If the gesture recognizer fires, it should now execute the code in the `linkTapped:` method and open the URL.

## Edit 2:

And because it actually fits in ~10 lines of code, here's a minimal view controller class as an example implementation.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView! //Check if connected correctly!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "linkTapped:")
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func linkTapped(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/") {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry , I didn't understand your code  , I have an UIImageView as an outlet and I've added the gesture in the viewDidLoad method , so can you please explain your code , I know this part  `if let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/") {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
   }` but how can I put the button ?!

Comment: And I'm not sure I understand your question :-) Nevertheless, I tried to edit the answer to include more specific instructions; maybe this will help you along.

Comment: Thanks That worked I was stuck in the action XD
I didn't put the ":" and the app kept crashing when I tap on the picture